# Finding Magic Numbers With Regex

Tags: regex, lua, syntax-highlighting, magic-numbers

I'm working with a syntax highlighting control and I have to specify all of the highlighted stuff with Regex.  I've completed everything else (keywords, functions, strings, comments, etc.) already but I can't come up with a good rule for magic numbers.  I'm using it for a Lua text editor if that helps at all.

I'm currently using `\d+` to detect the digits but the problem is that I end up with things like this:

[image]

As you can see, my variable names are also getting parts of them highlighted.

Does anybody know of a way to make this particular rule work correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want it to match within a name, so add a word boundary: `\b\d+\b`.

For floats, there could be a fractional part: `\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b`.

For floats, there could also be an exponent: `\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[Ee][+\-]?\d+)\b`.

Comment: For integers, there could be a `0x` prefix to hex constants, and more characters after that than just decimal digits.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say keep it simple when it comes to regex (i.e only write what you need, and no more).  The following will match group 2 to floats and ints that are being assigned:

```
(=\s*)([\d|\.]+)(\s*;)
```

- Group 1:  Context starts after '=' sign, accounting for any extra
  white space (the \s*).
- Group 2:  Will match against 1 or more digits
  (the \d) or periods (the .).
- Group 3:  Context ends at the ';',
  account for any extra white space before it (the \s*).

Hope that helps.